# vertically center subfloat figure

Tags: subfloats

How can I vertically center the taller figure on the right? I tried reading subfig package and there mentioned \savebox but I'm not sure if that can provide a solution. Please help. Thanks.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage[margin=0pt]{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[c][11cm][t]{.5\textwidth}
\vspace*{\fill}
\centering
\subfloat[a]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{./graphics/plots/ST034-1-4SG.pdf}
}
\par\vfill
\subfloat[b]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{./graphics/plots/ST034all.pdf}
}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[c][11cm][t]{.5\textwidth}
\vspace*{\fill}
\centering
\subfloat[c]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{./graphics/plots/ST034-SEC.pdf}
}
\end{minipage}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your two `minipage`s with little modifications can do the job (I additionally suppressed some spurious blank spaces)

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage[margin=0pt]{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[c]{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\subfloat[a]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{./graphics/plots/ST034-1-4SG.pdf}}\par
\subfloat[b]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{./graphics/plots/ST034all.pdf}}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[c]{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\subfloat[c]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{./graphics/plots/ST034-SEC.pdf}}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

Comment: Hi Gonzalo, thanks for your quick reply. Is there anyway to decrease the amount of vertical space between the two smaller figures (a and b)? I would like to save space for text underneath. Thanks.

Comment: @SpencerTrinh Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can better control the horizontal spacing by using `tabular`, exploiting the fact that by default it does vertical centering of the material with respect to the current line of text; instead of `\qquad` you can use any `\hspace` you want.

For adding space between the two images on the left, you can use

```
\addlinespace[2cm]
```

or whatever length, between the two rows (after `\\`, to be explicit).

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage[margin=0pt]{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\centering

\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \subfloat[a]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{./graphics/plots/ST034-1-4SG.pdf}}\\
  \subfloat[b]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{./graphics/plots/ST034all.pdf}}
\end{tabular}\qquad
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
\subfloat[c]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{./graphics/plots/ST034-SEC.pdf}}
\end{tabular}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The `demo` option is just for getting an output without your images.

[image]